# Encoding PDF binary data to base64 not working with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, encode

I'm trying to get a PDF stream return that comes from a API and parse it to base64 to embbed it in the client side, the body of the API request is returning something like this:

```
    %PDF-1.5
%����
4 0 obj
<<
/Type/XObjcect
/Subtype/Image
/Width 799
/Height 70
/ColorSpace/DeviceGray
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter/FlateDecode
/Length 5181
>>
stream
x���=H#�������A�&�)���B���4iba�&O8H
.
.
. 
(The rest was omitted)
```

I'm trying to parse to base64 this way:

```
console.log(typeof body); // STRING
const encoded = new Buffer.from(body).toString('base64'); //PDF NOT WORKING
```

But when I'm getting this base64 and embedding it on the html it says that the file can't be oppened, the same thing happens when I trying to save it as .PDF file.

When I try to parse to base64 the same pdf but this time from a downloaded pdf, the base64 code when embedded in the html works fine.

```
  fs.readFile('/home/user/downloaded.pdf', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(typeof data); //OBJECT
    const pdf = data.toString('base64'); //PDF WORKS
  });
```

I'm using `const request = require('request');` to make the requests.

Comment: Typeof `body` should be `Buffer` not a string, please show your code which make request. String can not contain binary data.

Comment: @h0x91B Thank you for your answear, and yeah you are right, I add "encoding: null" in my request and I'm getting a buffer now instead of a string. 
I thought that parsing this string to a buffer would do the same, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you make your request you should set option encoding to null for getting `Buffer` instead of `String`.

```
request({
    method: 'GET',
    encoding: null,
    uri: 'http://youdomain.com/binary.data'
}, (err, resp, data)=>{
    console.log(typeof data) //should be an Object
    console.log(data.toString('base64'))
})
```

Comment: Hi, i tried the above code. it works fine and i also get the type as an object. though the data i still get is gibberish. any idea of what might the reason be?

Comment: Using axios, I set `responseType: 'arrayBuffer'`, and `responseEncoding: 'binary'`. Now it works.Thank you any way, your answer pointed out the direction.

Answer (score 4):

I've found solution on this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/converting-pdf-binary-base64-nodejs-trick-end-andrew-ribeiro).
You need add to your request some config.

```
axios.get({
    url: "https...",
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
    responseEncoding: "binary",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const pdf2base64 = require('pdf-to-base64');
pdf2base64("test/sample.pdf")
    .then(
        (response) => {
            console.log(response);        }
    )
    .catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
```

Comment: Hi, here are some guidelines : *it is not recommended* to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes