# Convert binary to base64 in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, rest, pdf, base64

There's a direct download link that downloads a PDF on a GET request. When I make a get request using a REST client like the postman, a binary data is received in the response.
I want to convert this data to base64.
Now, this base64 string needs to be passed to other API which in turn sends the file to WhatsApp chat.
I successfully receive the document in WhatsApp but it is totally blank. The file size is the same as the source file, the same with the number of pages too.

```
var axios = require('axios');
let base64;
var config = {
    method: 'get',
    encoding: null,
    url: '.................',
};
  
axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
    // console.log(response.data, "-----------------------------------\n");
    console.log(typeof response.data);

   // base64 = Buffer.from(response.data).toString('base64');
   // base64 = Buffer.from(response.data).toString('base64');
   // base64 = new Buffer(response.data, "binary");
   // base64 = Buffer.concat(response.data);
   // base64 = new Buffer(response.data, "base64");

   base64 = response.data.toString('base64');
   var data = {...........};

   var config2 = {
    method: 'post',
    url: '...........',
    headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'x-auth-token': '...........', 
    'Host': '.............'
    },
    data : data
   };
  
   axios(config2)
   .then(function (response) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("error while sending");
  });

})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error, "error while requesting for the file");
});
```

I have tried the below solutions, none of them worked for me.

[Encoding PDF binary data to base64 not working with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968038/encoding-pdf-binary-data-to-base64-not-working-with-nodejs)

Comment: ware you able to solve the problem, ı have the same here

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I found another way that served my purpose.