# Convert incoming PDF Binary file having content type application/pdf into base64 in WSO Api Manager 3.2 with mediation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, esb, wso2-esb

**Description :** I am trying to convert the incoming pdf file which has content/type application/pdf into base64 using mediation with wso2 api manager 3.2 but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this. I have added the messageformatters and messagebuilders also in axis.xml but still not able to figure out. Any help from someone would be really appreciable.

**Added in Axis.xml**

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/pdf" 
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
<messageBuilder contentType="application/pdf" 
                            class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

**Response Mediation**

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="response.xml">
<property expression="$body/*" name="messageBody" scope="default" />
<property expression="base64Encode(get-property('messageBody'))" name="EncodeBody" scope="default" />
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="get-property('EncodeBody')" name="EncodeBody" />
</log>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/pdf" />
<property name="contentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/pdf" />
</sequence>
```

**Expected Output :**

```
{
    "data": {
        "file": "base64data"
    }
}
```

**Original Response**

[image]

**Error Logs**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-07 11:23:42,163] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} - Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: #Can not parse stream. MessageID: urn:uuid:407d7c54-df47-46aa-ada9-9cde9b3eebe1. Error>>> #getNewJsonPayload. Could not save JSON payload. Invalid input stream found. Payload is not a JSON string.
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:862)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder.processDocument(JsonStreamBuilder.java:43)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse_aroundBody4(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:371)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: #getNewJsonPayload. Could not save JSON payload. Invalid input stream found. Payload is not a JSON string.
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:846)
    ... 26 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-07 11:23:42,169] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} - {api:admin--CreditorWatchDownloadCreditReportPDF:v1.0.0} Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:452)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:215)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse_aroundBody4(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:371)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: #Can not parse stream. MessageID: urn:uuid:407d7c54-df47-46aa-ada9-9cde9b3eebe1. Error>>> #getNewJsonPayload. Could not save JSON payload. Invalid input stream found. Payload is not a JSON string.
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:862)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder.processDocument(JsonStreamBuilder.java:43)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:153)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: #getNewJsonPayload. Could not save JSON payload. Invalid input stream found. Payload is not a JSON string.
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:846)
    ... 26 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-05-07 11:23:42,173] ERROR {API_LOGGER.admin--CreditorWatchDownloadCreditReportPDF} - Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:452)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:215)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate_aroundBody0(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:73)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.mediate(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse_aroundBody4(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler.handleResponse(APIManagerExtensionHandler.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:371)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Similar to this link [Encoding PDF binary data to base64 not working with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968038/encoding-pdf-binary-data-to-base64-not-working-with-nodejs) but need to do it in wso2 api manager

Answer (score 0):

As per the shared stack trace, the correct formatters and builders are not picked during the mediation process. And API Manager was using the `JSONStreamBuilder` to build the message.

The API Manager v3.2.0 uses a centralized configuration to configure the XML artifacts. Therefore, if you have configured the Message Builders and Formatters by directly editing the `axis2.xml`, the configurations will be lost by the startup of the server. Perform the following configuration in the `<apim>/repository/conf/deployment.toml`

```
[[custom_message_formatters]]
class = "org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"
content_type = "application/pdf"

[[custom_message_builders]]
class = "org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"
content_type = "application/pdf"
```

and restart the server and retry the scenario.