# How to extract data URL from image binary data received from WhatsApp API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, whatsapp, data-uri

**Requirement**

I am using WhatsApp API to receive and send messages. Now, someone sent me an image and the response I am getting by API is in the form of binary data as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

(and ofcourse the binary data is far more lengthy than the screenshot)

**My requirement is to convert this string to Data URL so that I can display it in the browser.**

#######################################################################

**What I have tried**

I have tried the following as per googling for a bit but it is not helping.

```
const extractedImage = `data:${mimeType};base64,${Buffer.from(response.data).toString("base64")}`;
// where response.data gives the binary data of image and mimeType is image/jpeg
```

The string after the above conversion is as displayed below.

[image]

The Data URL is not valid and I am getting a blank output.
Please guide me how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution.

Just needed to mention

```
responseType: "arrayBuffer", responseEncoding: "binary"
```

while making the Axios API call and also adding "binary" parameter while converting to "base64"

```
Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString("base64");
```

Reference -> Check out the last comment by Andrew [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968038/encoding-pdf-binary-data-to-base64-not-working-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

I am using whatsapp cloud API from backend through node js, you can refer my solution and convert it to your use case.

You should not get the response like this.  The ideal response from the whatsApp API when we receive media messages is like this.

```
{
"entry": [
    {
        "changes": [
            {
                "field": "messages",
                "value": {
                    "contacts": [
                        {
                            "profile": {
                                "name": "XXXXXXX"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "messages": [
                        {
                            "from": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "id": "wamid.aisjdoiajsodiajsodasd\u003d",
                            "timestamp": "1657527108",
                            "type": "image"
                        }
                    ],
                    "metadata": {}
                }
            }
        ],
        "id": "124071984791824"
    }
],
"object": "whatsapp_business_account"
```

}

From there you can get the image id through accessing objects like this.

```
 let media_id=req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].image.id;
```

From there you have to call [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#retrieve-media-url) to get the URL for the media_id we have. then you have to use that URL to download the media from [this link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#download-media).

Comment: Yes, I did everything you mentioned above. The screenshot posted above is the binary data that I am getting after calling the Media URL. Now the thing is I am getting the image but I need the Data URL to simply display the image on the bowser, not download it.

Comment: No. I think that is not the optimal solution here.  Store the image in some static storages like S3 and get it back for FE when needed. So even when you need to scale the application you can minimize the API calls to whatsApp and also it is quicker too.

Comment: Yeah that's also an option but still there must be something I could do to display the binary data as an image. I have seen few more similar queries here but seems like no one has found any optimal solution yet.